# Append Rows of Datatable to Excel with Skip Some Columns on Excel on C#

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have one-to-one data in a datatable with my excel template. (The column names are the same.) I will print the data in this datatable exactly to the excel template, but I want to skip some columns, for example Column2. (I have 5000 lines of data, I do not want to break the Excel template.) Too long waiting for ClosedXml Save operation, I couldn't solve the reason. I would be very happy if you could help.

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYNy0.png)

[My Code on Gist](https://gist.github.com/emreozguruoglu/9662289d3d4d0348868ee1ff68160388)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your own IEnumerable of an anonymous object and use the `worksheet.FirstCell().InsertData()` method to dump the entire enumerable into the worksheet.

I didn't test it, but the code would be something like this:

```
var data = dtData.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => new { Column1 = r["Column1"], Column2 = r["Column2"] })
    .ToList();

worksheet.FirstCell().InsertData(data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's resolved my problem.